# C++ twodimensional vector causing buffer overflow

Tags: c++, ubuntu, multidimensional-array, vector

I made a "game of life" program, where you insert the size, the living cells and the speed of the game. Unfortunately my program isn't working. I narrowed down the problem to the vector> rules function, and I guess it has to do something with too high or low numbers. 
this code compiles, but as soon as I come to the rules part I get the following error:

```
==3944==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x604000000100 at pc 0x000000518258 bp 0x7ffdd648f5d0 sp 0x7ffdd648f5c8
```

I tried to change the unsigned integer values to normal integers but theres just a warning popping up then. I made everything else work but I cant seem to find a way to make this work. 
I appreciate any help!

If it helps, I work on a ubuntu operating system, with clang as my compiler.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

void rowsandcolumns (int row, int column) {

    int rowwhole = floor (row);
    int columnwhole = floor (column);

    if (row <=0 || column <=0 || row != rowwhole || column != columnwhole) {
        throw runtime_error ("Nur positive ganze Zahlen erlaubt");
    }
}

vector<vector<int>> rules (vector<vector<int>> cleanBoard, int row, int column, vector<vector<int>> secondBoard) {

    for (int i = 1; i <= row+1; i++) { 

        for (int j = 1; j <= column+1; j++) {

            int x;
            int a = cleanBoard [i-1][j-1];
            int b = cleanBoard [i][j-1];
            int c = cleanBoard [i+1][j-1];
            int d = cleanBoard [i-1][j];
            int e = cleanBoard [i+1][j];
            int f = cleanBoard [i-1][j+1];  
            int g = cleanBoard [i][j+1];    
            int h = cleanBoard [i+1][j+1];
            int mitte = cleanBoard [i][j];
            cout << cleanBoard[i][j];

            x = a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h;

            if (x < 2 && mitte == 1) {

                secondBoard [i][j] = 0;
            }

            else if ((mitte == 1 && x == 2) || x == 3) {

                secondBoard [i][j] = 1;
            }

            else if (mitte == 1 && x > 3) {

                secondBoard [i][j] = 0;
            }

            else if (mitte == 0 && x == 3) {

                secondBoard [i][j] = 1;
            }
            else break;
        }
    }

    return secondBoard;
}

double gamespeed() {

    double speed;
    cout << "Geben sie nun die Geschwindigkeit ein, mit welcher sich 'Game of Life' entwickeln soll. (Empfohlen 0.5 Sekunden bis 2 Sekunden)\n";
    cin >> speed;
    cout << '\n';
    return speed;
}

int main () {

    //initialisierung der wichtigen Variablen
    int alive = 1;
    int dead = 0;
    double row, column, x, y, speed;

    //Eingabe der Reihen und Spalten und Check, ob dies erlaubt ist
    cout << "Geben sie die Dimensionen row (Zeilen) und column (Spalten) für Conways 'Game of Life' an! (Ganze positive Zahlen)\n";
    cin >> row >> column;
    rowsandcolumns(row, column);

    //Erstellung des nxm Feldes
    vector<int> v(column);
    vector<vector<int>> cleanBoard(row, v);

    //Erstellung des Spielfeldes, wo jede Zelle tot ist
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {      
        for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
            cleanBoard[i][j] = dead;
            cout << cleanBoard[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    //Eingabe der eigenen lebenden Zellen und Check, ob eine richtige Zahl eingegeben wurde
    do {    
        cout << "Geben sie nun die Koordinaten ein, an welcher Stelle sie eine lebende Zelle platzieren wollen. Vorher Zeile, dann Spalte! (Geben sie mindestens einmal 0 ein, um das Spiel zu starten)\n";
        cin >> x >> y;

        int newx = floor (x);
        int newy = floor (y);
        if (x < 0 || y < 0 || newx != x || newy != y || x > row || y > column) {
            throw runtime_error ("Nur positive ganze Zahlen zwischen 1 und den eingegebenen Dimensionen möglich.");
        }
        if (x != 0 || y != 0){
            x -= 1;
            y -= 1;
            cleanBoard[x][y] = alive;
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {      
                for (int j = 0; j < column; j++) {
                    cout << cleanBoard[i][j] << " ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            x += 1;
            y += 1;
        }
    } while (x != 0 || y != 0);

    cout << '\n';

    //Zeiteingabe
    speed = gamespeed();

    //Start des Spiels und Spielablauf
    vector<vector<int>> secondBoard;
    for (int u = 1; 0 < u; u--) {
        rules(cleanBoard, row, column, secondBoard);
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < secondBoard.size(); i++) {      
            for (unsigned j = 0; j < secondBoard[i].size(); j++) {
                cout << secondBoard[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cleanBoard = secondBoard;
        cout << "STRG+Z zum abbrechen";
        usleep(speed*1000);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I suspect an out of bounds in " for (int i = 1; i <= row+1; i++) { for (int j = 1; j <= column+1; j++) {"

Comment: Iow, stop fighting zero-based indexing; its part of the language. Just embrace it.

Comment: Definitely out of bounds error, since the loops  in `rule()` access elements out of bounds (repeatedly) of `cleanBoard`.   Also there are assignments to `secondBoard[i][j]` where the `secondBoard` passed from `main()` has zero elements in both dimensions.     In short, you've tried to be too clever with vector indexing, and (to paraphrase Stroustrup) are shooting your leg off repeatedly in the loops.

Comment: Okay, so basically just allow the loop to access negative numbers and giving the vector secondBoard his needed size?
if i do that i get a runtime error: 
runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x61a000000680 overflowed to 0x61a000000668

Comment: No, it is not just about "allowing the loop to access negative numbers".    It is about ensuring `i-1`, `i`, `i+1`, `j-1`, `j`, and `j+1` are ALL valid indices when used as such.

Comment: Alright, i expanded my board to n+2 and assigned everything dead, so it can handle my requests. then i did the same for the secondboard, so my program knows how much space it needs. i also edited my else tree, so everything in secondboard gets a new dead or alive. and lastly i changed the 0 or 1s to dead or alives. Still doesnt work for me tho. this time i get the error: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the rules function where you have the two for-loops.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= row+1; i++) { 
  for (int j = 1; j <= column+1; j++) {
```

Some of the calls to cleanBoard are out of bounds. if rows is 3,int i will go until it is no longer <= 3+1. So, the last loop will have int i = 4. with this line...

```
int c = cleanBoard [i+1][j-1];
```

You're trying to do cleanBoard[5][j-1], but cleanBoard[5] doesn't exist, it is only initialized up to [row][column]. The fix would be something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= row-1; i++) {
  for (int j = 1; j <= column-1; j++) {
```

Edit: Theres also another bug somewhere, I'm not so sure about how to fix it though. The error I got was

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555631a in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::operator[] (
    this=0x18, __n=1) at /usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043
1043        return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just working in code, draw out your board visually so you can see what you are trying to achieve

```
    c0  c1  c2  ... cn  cn+1     
r0 :   :___:___:...:___:   :
r1 :   |___|___|...|___|   :
r2 :   |___|___|...|___|   :
   :   :   :   :   :   :   :
   :   :___:___:   :___:   :
rn :   |___|___|...|___|   :
rn+1   :   :   :   :   :   :
```

You can immediately see that the last column is cn + 1; therefore the size of the vector is cn + 2.

Also, when the for loop does the checks, it only needs to go from 1 to cn: not cn+1 since the code searches all the cells around the current cell and the board only extends from 1 to cn.  Similar problem  with the rows.

When debugging manually, you can also use the diagram to work out which cell it is checking.

```
a  d  f
b     g
c  e  h
```